# Creating custom fonts

Tags: fonts, cocos2d-iphone, glyph, sparrow-framework

I developed a game with Cocos2D a while back, and used [Glyph Designer](http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com/#!prettyPhoto)

Is it possible to use Glyph Desiger with a non-cocos2d project, or is there any other framework you can use to make custom bitmap fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Glyph Designer can also create fonts usable by [Sparrow Framework](http://gamua.com/sparrow/) and by the projects in the [Learning iOS Game Programming](http://www.71squared.com/) book. Generally speaking you can write a custom loader for practically any game engine since the .fnt format is rather self-explanatory. It would be helpful though if that engine already had support for texture atlases and bitmap font rendering.

There are other bitmap font tools (Hiero, BMFont), but they're less than ideal for Mac/iOS developers. A viable alternative might be [bmGlyph](http://www.bmglyph.com/) as it is a native Mac app.

Answer (score 0):

[Glyphite.com](https://www.glyphite.com) can help you design Bitmap fonts right from your browser. It exports in the standard BMFont format, so it works with Cocos2D, Sparrow, and many other frameworks. You can layer more effects to create complex fonts with Glyphite.com than you can in any other Bitmap font designer.
(Disclosure: I work for Glyphite.com)